# "I was really thinking" vs. "I really was thinking"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order

Which one of the following is correct?

> - I was really thinking to do that.
> - I really was thinking to do that.

Comment: Both are *grammatical*, but which one gets the correct point across depends on what you want to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I was really thinking to do that.*
>   You might have assumed I was thinking about doing *this*, but actually ***that*** is what I have in mind (the word *really* confirms *that* as the option being considered).
>
> *I really was thinking to do that.*
>   You might have assumed I had no real plans, but actually I was really ***thinking*** of doing that (the word *really* confirms *the intention to do something*).

In both cases, the word *really* implies the speaker thinks his audience may be labouring under a misapprehension (about the specific plan, or the fact of having any serious plan at all).

Note that both OP's examples are [generally considered](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/30634/2637) informal/non-standard. [*Thinking **to do***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%20was%20really%20thinking%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22was%20thinking%20to%20do%22&oq=%22was%20thinking%20to%20do%22&gs_l=serp.3...4627.7394.6.7913.13.13.0.0.0.0.68.594.13.13.0...0.0...1c.1.0c4mgYfSXkA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1385&bih=880) is far less common than the "standard" forms [*thinking **of doing***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%20was%20really%20thinking%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22was%20thinking%20of%20doing%22&oq=%22was%20thinking%20of%20doing%22&gs_l=serp.3...10552.11785.5.12079.7.7.0.0.0.0.84.389.7.7.0...0.0...1c.1.ESl1BaJz_ps&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1385&bih=880) (or [***about*** doing](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22was%20thinking%20about%20doing%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)).

Answer (score 0):

The more usual verb is *think about*, followed by the *-ing* form of the subsequent verb. Where you place *really* changes the emphasis. *I really was thinking about doing that* might follow a suggestion by someone else that you weren’t going to do it. *I was really thinking about doing that* is more neutral, and might occur unprompted. The meaning of both can be nuanced by the way in which they are pronounced.

Answer (score 0):

*I was really thinking to do that* means that I wasn't thinking **a little bit** about doing that, nor **somewhat**: I was thinking **a lot** about doing it;

*I really was thinking to do that* means that it is true that I was thinking about doing that; you, or someone, said that I wasn't at all thinking about doing that, and that previous statement is not true.

Also, I prefer *about doing that* rather than *to do that* in both instances.

Comment: I disagree. You first interpretation is possible in some contexts, but far more often *I was really thinking to X* is used to clarify that you were in fact thinking of *X-ing* (rather than, for example, *Y-ing*).